# In the MCU, how did they decide to use a subtitle for the movie instead of numbers?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, title-explanation

A question popped into my mind.
At the beginning of the MCU we got movies numbered like *Iron Man 2* or *Iron Man 3*, But at one point, we got subtitles like *Thor: Ragnarok* or *Spider-Man: Homecoming*.

For the last one, my guess is that there's too many Spider-Man movies, so they need to add it to clarify for which universe you're in.

But what is the rule of naming the title or numbering it? I know for sure that it's not all recent movies that have a second name because we have *Captain Marvel* without subtitle.

Comment: FWIW there are quite a few "just name" films but the only numbered ones are _Iron Man_ and _Guardians of the Galaxy_.

Comment: The first movie never has a subname (*maybe because they don’t want to sound to optimistic*). I guess Spider-Man reboot had it because he had already made an appearance in CW and they knew they are gonna hit a home run with Spidey. (Remember, when Ironman were made, the MCU didn’t have their hopes very high as they do now.). Captain Marvel, although being known to fans, isn’t that famous as the others. That’s why maybe.

Comment: Looking at it from another way, the “subname” could almost be a spoiler. They couldn’t call CM as ***Captain Marvel: Saving Private Skrulls*** 

Comment: It's also worth noting that with the exception of _Captain America: The First Avenger_ and _Spider-Man: Homecoming_ none of the "first" films for a character have a subname.

Comment: @Shreedhar It could be *Captain Marvel: Space Ranger Karen* ^.^

Comment: In assuming it's 'focus grouped'

Comment: Is it a MCU-only decision? It feels that other sagas took the same way. Terminator (1,2,3, Genesys,...), X-men (1,2,Last Stand,...), Pirates of the Caribbeans, Transformers. (Note: I am not sure of my examples since I used to watch movies in France where it is common to change movie titles).

Comment: How are we forgetting Star Wars? this is where it all began : **Star Wars Episode 4: A New Hope**

Comment: @Shreedhar was that the official name back in the days ? or just added when more movie came out ?

Comment: I’m not sure about the “Episode 4” part in the title but they would have surely called it Star Wars a new hope. And Star Wars empire strikes back etc. Maybe Lucas film started this trend; who knows ‍♂️

Comment: @Shreedhar It was originally just "Star Wars" in 1977.  It was re-released in 1978 and 1979 as "Star Wars", and then in 1981 and 1982 as "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope".  The first use of "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope" was actually in 1979 for the ["The Art of Star Wars"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Star_Wars) book, ready for The Empire Strikes Back to be released in 1980

Comment: I would guess there are extensive psychological studies about this.  If it is numbered, there is a reluctance to see it until you've seen the preceding entries.  Less of that if it is named without that.  I for one, tend to do that--lots of mystery series the previous books don't matter so much, but I'm still unlikely to read book 4 without reading 1-3 first.  That's great for DVD release, but less so for box office sales, which is where the hype is created.

Comment: @eshier As a single point of anecdotal data, I feel like I'm in the opposite camp.  I never really kept up with the MCU, seeing the odd franchise/movie here and there.  Given the lack of numbers in some series; I've been reluctant to watch any not knowing if it's the first in a series or not.  When I see them on Netflix with a name like "Captain America: The First Avenger"; I have no idea it's the first one of it's arc, so I'm less inclined to click on it and watch it.

Comment: all this discussion, it's probably just they had different people naming movies and came up with different style of titles lol

Comment: @Huangism: sure, Disney are famous for not sweating the details of movie marketing.

Comment: @eshier: there might be studies. Fairly famously, Paramount thought putting “Part II” in the title of the sequel to “The Godfather” [would put audiences off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godfather_Part_II#Filming), but then once the movie was a success, many sequels followed suit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the absence of quotes from the studio (I googled a whole bunch and found nothing!), here are all the titles of released movies, grouped by series:

- Iron Man

  - Iron Man 2
  - Iron Man 3
- The Incredible Hulk

  - *[sorry Bruce :( ]*
- Thor

  - Thor: The Dark World
  - Thor: Ragnarok
- Captain America: The First Avenger

  - Captain America: The Winter Soldier
  - Captain America: Civil War
- The Avengers

  - Avengers: Age of Ultron
  - Avengers: Infinity War
  - Avengers: Endgame
- Guardians of the Galaxy

  - Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2
- Ant-Man

  - Ant-Man and the Wasp
- Doctor Strange
- Spider-Man: Homecoming

  - Spider-Man: Far From Home
- Black Panther
- Captain Marvel

It looks like the first appearance of a character or team always gets titled with just their name, unless:

1. There's already a popular 2002 movie from a different studio with that title (*Spider-Man*); or
2. There's an unprecedented crossover movie coming out next year that you really want to market, and the movie you want to market it with (*Captain America: The First Avenger*) could use an [alternative title for countries that aren't so keen on America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_The_First_Avenger#Theatrical)

So far, all sequels from *The Dark World* onwards have had subtitles — except for *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*, and *Ant-Man and the Wasp*.

- Arguably, Ant-Man and the Wasp is the first movie featuring both heroes as a duo (because Hope wasn't the Wasp in *Ant-Man*), hence no subtitle.
- The team featured in the MCU *Guardians* movies is the team from [the second volume of the *Guardians of the Galaxy* comic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_(2008_team)#Publication_history), so its title may be a reference to that.

Moving on to pure speculation, the subtitles for sequel movies in general might be following the idea of comics storylines having titles in their own right ([Planet Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Hulk), [Maximum Carnage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_Carnage), etc.)

They also might help to avoid the impression that each character's movies are a standalone series. *Captain America: Civil War*, for example, features a strong arc for Iron Man, development for Black Widow, Wanda and Vision, and the introductions of Black Panther and Spider-Man, alongside Cap's own story. Calling it *Captain America 3* might have sat weirdly with the movie's actual content. (Of course, history is littered with smarter idiots than me speculating about [the effect of titles on movie-goers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godfather_Part_II#Filming).)

---

### Phase 4 update

On 20th July 2019, Marvel announced two sequels and four title character debuts. *[Black Widow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Widow_(2020_film))*, *[The Eternals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Eternals_(film))* and *[Blade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Blade)* are titled with just their lead character/team's name, while *[Thor: Love and Thunder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Thor:_Love_and_Thunder_(2021))* proves that the *colon: subtitle* pattern is alive and well.

However, the Doctor Strange sequel and Shang Chi debut swap colon for preposition and conjunction respectively with *[Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Doctor_Strange_in_the_Multiverse_of_Madness_(2021))* and *[Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Shang-Chi_and_the_Legend_of_the_Ten_Rings_(2021))*, proving that even 11 years deep in the game, Marvel still has the power and the courage to innovate titles like no other studio. (No other studio [at all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birds_of_Prey_(2020_film)).)

Comment: It's worth noting that _Captain America: The First Avenger_ was originally titled _The First Avenger: Captain America_.

Comment: Also GotG Vol 2 is sort of a title referring to the cassette tape I believe.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: or [the comic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_(2008_team)#Publication_history)?

Comment: Isn't *Guardians of the Galaxy* actually *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 1*? Or was it retroactively titled that after the release of Vol. 2? I'm sure I've seen Vol. 1 used in at least some (official) places, but I don't know if that's been consistent.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Officially it is _Guardians of the Galaxy_, look at the DVD covers, for example.

Comment: *Sorry Bruce :(* is a mighty odd name for a film.

Comment: Doesn't *"The Incredible Hulk"* the second movie ? The first one is *"Hulk"* no ? So they put pre-title in title also right ?!

Comment: It seems like "Ant Man and the Wasp", "Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness" and "Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings" are pretty much equivalent to a subtitle. They're both "<Name of Hero> <phrase describing the sequel>"; the only difference is whether or not the phrase happens to start with a colon.

Comment: @TinyDoowy: *Hulk* was the first movie featuring that character, but doesn't share any continuity with the Marvel Cinematic Universe, so it's not on this list.

Comment: @AdmiralJota personally I like my heroes to have colons, and for those colons to be prominently displayed in all marketing materials.